# Is It possible to set Image as ScreenSaver in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to know that Is It possible in Android to set an Image as screenSaver.. I am not sure about the feasibily of screen saver...That is when the phone is Idle, then Instead of showing the black blank screen, my application check the Idle time using `OnUserInteraction()` method and set an Image as screen saver...?? Please let me know If anybody know about this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onUserInteraction() is deprecated for a start, and it only listens for events on your Activity.

Secondly, having such a screensaver would require that you use [WakeLocks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html), which consume extra battery. And for a screensaver type app, the battery usage would be extremely high.

You might want to look into Daydreams now, assuming you're fine with Android 4.2 and above only.

Comment: Yes..But by using this wake lock Is it possible that I can show am Image as a screensaver?

Comment: If you can figure out how to start your Activity when the phone is idle for a while, then yes. But it will be very battery intensive to keep the screen on the whole time, as even the CPU and GPU must run then.